# How to expand folder branch in Project Window Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, subdirectory, folderbrowserdialog, java-package

Sometimes I close folder/package in Project Tool Window and then I should click **every folder** in it to open them . How to avoid this and open all folders/packages quickly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## <kbd>*</kbd> on numpad

Also see IDEA guide about [Title bar context menu](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html#d984828e228) and customize project window as you need.

Navigate to any folder / package by name! Use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>(on Mac <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) in the pop-up window type name of folder / package, and end of name add <kbd>/</kbd>, for example `src/`. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html) guide for more understanding.

Use the great feature **Speed Search** for quick navigation:

[image]

And also use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to hide Project Tool Window.

Comment: `* on numpad` what is equivalent on Mac short keyboard?

Comment: @Prostak also `*` on numpad, I suggest you to change this shortcut to `8` key. For do that: `Preferences | Keymap` and here find `Fully Expand Tree Node` and assign `8` key

Comment: there is no `Preferences | Keymap`. There is `Preferences | Keyboard`, but there is no `Keymap` in there also...

Comment: Thank you!!! I was getting tired of restarting my IDE and having to re-expand all of my packages by clicking on them one by one.

Answer (score 7):

after every press numpad * folders will be expaned more and more